# French string not stored proper in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, french

I am trying to store french string in mysql DB but it not get proper stored and changed some characters and not get display proper in my webpage

Original string: Bonjour Mr/Mme « Nom de famille du prospect », je suis « votre prénom » d’Europ Assistance La Téléassistance…

Stored string : Bonjour Mr/Mme Â« Nom de famille du prospect Â», je suis Â« votre prÃ©nom Â» dâ€™Europ Assistance La TÃ©lÃ©assistanceâ€¦

I have tried with many solutions

- header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');,
- Collation is utf8_unicode_ci,
- Used SET NAMES UTF8,
- tried mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8") when select from DB,
- Also tried with ISO-8859-1

Also tried many HTML functions but did not work
character_set_name is utf-8

character_set_name is utf-8

Comment: You must have utf8 all the way through. so check the connection string if there is also a utf8

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share?

Comment: @NicoHaase Nothing to show in code just simple mysql query to select string from DB

Comment: Well, then there is some bug in your configuration. But as you haven't shown any code samples to trigger the problem nor the database configuration, it's close to impossible to provide help

Comment: @nbk how to check connection string for utf-8, are you talking about my $conn DB connection variable?

Comment: Please post you code with the connection string. You seem also to have a **sql injection problem**. And check @Dharman link

Answer (score 0):

Check the collation type of your MySql tables, it shloud be set at "utf8" to correctly encode accents on letters. You could also try "utf8mb4".

Comment: Thanks for reply,
It is already utf-8

Comment: Do not use `utf8`, use only `utf8mb4`

Comment: @Dharman tried not working